# Metronome app that "listens"

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, software-recommendation, music

I'm looking for a metronome app for my iPhone with a BPM analyzer, so it should be able to recognize if I play too slow, too fast or just in tempo.

Comment: What instrument do you play?

Comment: @shallowThought an electric guitar.

Comment: Uberchord is very good.

Comment: @shallowThought Yeah, I know, but in Uberchord it's just a "level" in a "game" and I want this function as a standalone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rhythm Sight Reading Trainer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rhythm-sight-reading-trainer/id396302174?mt=8) seems to do the job.

It's able to use microphone as an input device and other apps like Beatly or CrossBeat offer tap input only.